# What is the proper way to map a list object to AWS API Gateway for a POST request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My mapping template is:

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Lists",
    "Item": {
    "listid": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
            },
        "title": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.title')"
            },
        "places": {
            "L": $input.path('$.places')
        }
    }
}
```

The error i get is:

```
{"__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException",
      "Message": "Expected null"}
```

If i change the places object to "S" and pass in a string, everything works fine, but I can't get a list to pass through properly.

Here is my test request body for the API Gateway Console:

```
{
  "title": "Title",
  "places": ["place 1", "place 2"]
}
```

And here is the request after transformations:

```
Endpoint request body after transformations: { 
"TableName": "Lists",
"Item": {
"listid": {
        "S": "test-invoke-request"
        },
    "title": {
        "S": "Title"
        },
    "places": {
        "L": ["place 1","place 2"]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you're testing in the API Gateway console could you post a sample input and output for the template? This is in the Logs for the request under 'Method request body before transformations' and 'Endpoint request body after transformations'. It looks correct to me, assuming $.places is always an array. I don't know if it would work correctly if $.places was not an array or not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html

For a list of strings the proper attribute value is "SS". "L" is reserved for a list of attribute value objects.

So to get my original request body to pass through I had to reformat as:

```
    { "title": "Title2",
      "places": [{"S": "place 1"}, {"S": "place 2"}]
     }
```